# wso2 "complete and same" master-datasources.xml on all five WSO2 API-M components

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I'm setting WSO2 APIM HA in distributed environment and I have some challanges using this [documentation.](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Installing+and+Configuring+the+Databases)

1. Documentation states: *Note: When configuring clustering, ignore the WSO2_CARBON_DB data source configuration.*

**Question is**, do I really cannot use CARBON db instead od UM un REG databases in HA?

2. Documentation mentions to configure following:

   - AM DB - in the Publisher, Store, and Key Manager nodes
   - UM DB - in the Publisher, Store, and Key Manager nodes
   - REG DB - in the API Publisher and Store nodes. (single tenant)
   - MB DB - in the Traffic manager nodes (each TM own DB)

**Question is**, can I completely fill one `master-datasources.xml` file and overwrite it on all components so I would not have to edit it on each server? (only editing the second TM datasource to aim to the second MB DB)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is fine if you completely fill only one master-datasource.xml file & overwrite it on all other components. (except `WSO2_MB_STORE_DB` which is `MB DB`)

But `MB DB (WSO2_MB_STORE_DB )` has to be separate for each node. As this DB is used for traffic as well as internally by Throttling policies, which has very high rate of DB transactions.

It will work if you don't keep `WSO2_MB_STORE_DB` separate, but it will have large number of DB transactions which can slower down your single DB. So it's **Highly Advisable** to maintain separate DB on each node. It will also help you in easy DEBUGGING in PROD environments.

Comment: Yes, as I wrote, I'll have separate MB_STORE DBs for each TM.
and maybe you know the answer to the first question, about using CARBON_DB instead of UM and REG DBs? :)

Comment: You can edit `WSO2_CARBON_DB` if you want. As I was referring to clustering documentations, in example they have shown use of `mysql` db. You can refer this [link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Setting+up+the+Database#SettinguptheDatabase-Configuringthemanagernode)

Comment: Also make sure whenever you change default DB, you have to add respective DB driver jar file into `<APIM_HOME>/repository/components/lib`. (As ORACLE will require `ojdbc6.jar`)

Comment: yeah, that's clear, I just was confused by the note: *Note: When configuring clustering, ignore the WSO2_CARBON_DB data source configuration.*